# Deploy Django static files with Apache/Gunicorn

Tags: django, apache, gunicorn

I am using Apache2 with Gunicorn/Django to deploy my app.
However my app doesn't display the static files like CSS sheets etc.

I read many topics but I think I need help because I probably missed something...

Setting.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/media/myapp/static/'
```

Apache2 VHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.fr
    ServerAlias www.myapp.fr myapp.fr

    DocumentRoot /home/django-project/myapp/

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/

    ProxyPass /static/ !
    Alias /static/ /var/www/media/myapp/static/

    <Directory /home/django-project/myapp/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What happens when you make a request for a static file? Do you get a 404 response?

Comment: Yes indeed. And this is the displayed path : <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css">

Comment: Ok, and the file definitely exists in `/var/www/media/myapp/static/`?

Comment: Yes that's why I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the exclusion for for `ProxyPass /static/ !` should come before  `ProxyPass /`

```
ProxyPass /static/ !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
Alias /static/ /var/www/media/myapp/static/
```

Otherwise the static request will be sent to gunicorn, which will return a 404.

The [ProxyPass documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) says:

> The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins.

Comment: I was struggling for 4 days in a row to server static files, this answer helped me to fix it and launch to production, tnx